# How to embed the Python interpreter in a Qt app?

Tags: python, qt

Is there a straightforward way to embed the Python interpreter in a Qt application? I am hoping for a cross-platform solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose of [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/).  It supports Windows, Linux, and Mac OS.