# Python console prints output differently than sypder console

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a python code that takes measurements off of a HP LCR Meter and collects the data for us in various ways. I recently created a GUI for imputing initial conditions for employees not comfortable modifying variables in the code. Everything works except for 1 thing. WE use the latest python xy so python version 2.6.6 with pyqt and spyder on a windows 7 PC.

Normally we would open the code in spyder. But opening spyder takes a while and my supervisor liked the ability to just double click on the file which opens the GUI with a python console window to print errors and various information as you would see in spyder.

As can be seen in the screen shots provided, there is a initial machine setup mode for setting up the device to be scanned by the LCR Meter and there are two user inputs that the code prompts. On spyder it prints these prompts nicely in the console but in the python console opened without spyder it continuously prints `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running` Weird thing is you can still just push enter twice as normal and the code will run like normal. But its going to be confusing to basically everyone but me.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

[Here are the pictures of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfqU7.jpg)

Here is the code that prompts the input.

```
    lcr = visa.instrument('GPIB::17')
        #clear the instrument
        lcr.write('*RST;*CLS')
        #enable operation complete notification
        lcr.write('*OPC')
        if parallel:
            lcr.write('FUNC:IMP CPG')   #Parallel capacitance, conductance model
        else:
            lcr.write('FUNC:IMP CSRS')   #Series capacitance, resistance model
        lcr.write('APER '+integration+','+averages)
        lcr.write('OUTP:HPOW ON')
        lcr.write('OUTP:DC:ISOL OFF')
        lcr.write('VOLT '+vac)
        lcr.write('TRIG:SOUR BUS')

        if zero == True:
            #set open correction parameters
            lcr.write('DISP:PAGE CSET')
            lcr.write('CORR:LENG 1')
            lcr.write('CORR:METH SING')
            lcr.write('CORR:LOAD CPG')
            lcr.write('CORR:USE 10') 
            lcr.write('CORR:SPOT1:STATE ON')    
            lcr.write('CORR:SPOT2:STATE OFF')    
            lcr.write('CORR:SPOT3:STATE OFF')
            lcr.write('CORR:SPOT1:FREQ '+frequency)
            #perform open correction -> unprobe device\   
            raw_input('Unprobe DUT and press ENTER to continue...')
            lcr.write('CORR:SPOT1:OPEN')
            lcr.write('CORR:OPEN:STATE ON')
            lcr.write('DISP:PAGE MEAS')
            #poll lcr to determine measurment state
            lcr.write('*OPC?')    
            done = lcr.read()    
            while done == 0:
                lcr.write('*OPC?')
                done = lcr.read()        
                time.sleep(0.5)
            #reprobe device                                
            raw_input('Probe DUT, then press ENTER')                
        lcr.write('FREQ '+frequency)
```

The Prompts are the two `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why you get continuous messages in your console, is that system logs use same output-stream than your app.

Spyder is nice program, which just embeds IPython or Python(backup) console in QT window, you can use similar solution - just use Qt4 to draw window, which includes IPython console

What you need to do is this([source](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/IPython/DATA/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/example-embed.py?r=cbdc960ec29e75d10d9c8897fcd2be309b663fa3)):

```
def embed_ipython(window):
    "wrapper funcs - works < IPython 0.11"
    from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
    ipshell = IPShellEmbed(user_ns = dict(w = window))
    ipshell()
```

Here ‘window’ is a central object of some kind that you want to expose to IPython (to manipulate, test various methods, etc).

GUI app initialization would be like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    embed_ipython(window)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Some additional readings:

- QT4 tutorial: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/
- Similar topic - how to embed python console: [How to embed a Python interpreter in a PyQT widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758159/how-to-embed-a-python-interpreter-in-a-pyqt-widget)
- IPython and QT console: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html

Comment: I tried adding what you put here into my main code, however when I run it, it pops up my GUI first which works as normal but to run the ipython shell I have to close my GUI. I want them to run at the same time but can only run one or the other. The ipython shell portion of my code is screen captured at this link http://imgur.com/cy5Eu           Thanks for your help btw