# Developing a GUI for python application in windows

Tags: python

I am doing a project in python... Recently sir told to add a GUI for it as I was running it in command prompt and he could not understand it.On his suggestion I downloaded **PYQT** for windows.I am working on **Python 2.7**.How can I run my applicaiton from PYQT UI? And also how to print the results that my app produces in **PYQT** rather than in command prompt? Should i use **QProcess()**?... Please help....

I actually found a code here- It is embedding a python interpreter in PYQT

[How to embed a Python interpreter in a PyQT widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758159/how-to-embed-a-python-interpreter-in-a-pyqt-widget)

Comment: What have you tried? Also, have you tried the standard Python GUI library, TkInter? It requires no download and has plenty of tutorials: http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Comment: My teacher wanted me to use only PYQT

Comment: Then I'll recommend to read a PyQt tutorial first: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/

Comment: I have downloaded PYQT and tried few of simple applicaions like hello world, calculator