# Python Programs Console inside pyqt GUI

Tags: python, pyqt

Alright so im wanting to create a pyqt gui that has little consoles inside the program that things can be printed to. let me explain further more. so if you would run a program without any gui interface like this

```
import os
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello " + str(name) = "How are you?"
os.system('pause')
```

everything would run inside of the cmd. i am wanting to make a pyqt gui that is basicly the cmd but i would like to add other buttons around the embedded console if someone could teach me how to make this that would be amazing. thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you want to create a console where python code is executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed a Python interpreter in a PyQT widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758159/how-to-embed-a-python-interpreter-in-a-pyqt-widget)

Comment: @eyllanesc i dont want code to be able to be executable

Comment: Could you explain me better

Comment: @eyllanesc im trying to make a program that prints things into a console in a gui. in the code i am going to be printing things like name: birthday: Favorite food: but i dont wan't the console in the gui to be able to accept code back like the python shell

Comment: similar to this: http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/images/QPlainTextEditFind%20Example.png ?

Comment: @eyllanesc somewhat yes. the text part where it says hello hello will code be able to load in there? like if i where to do print name: Mark time.sleep(1) print birthday: 1/11/1111

Comment: This code will be in another script and you want the output to be displayed in the console?

Comment: no all in the same script

Comment: In a gui there should be blocking code like `sleep()`, it is better to use a timer.

Comment: Neither `os.system ('pause')` since the widget will maintain the impression.

Comment: yea the os.system was just en example

Comment: What I understand is what you want in a gui to print texts and get attached

Comment: Am I right in what I say?

Comment: You can be precise in your code since your question is broad.

Comment: Do you want to print on the console?

Comment: no not in the console of the program but in a little gui console

Comment: You could show me an image of what you want to understand.

Comment: @eyllanesc http://prntscr.com/ecq4d3

Comment: The script "print ...." is changeable or fixed?

Comment: Do you just want the output of this script to be displayed on the console?

Comment: fixed? meaning the person who runs the program cant delete it from the gui console if so yes i dont want them to be able to edit it in the console.

Comment: @eyllanesc is this possible to code?

Answer (score -1):

You're thinking too much into this.

You want to:

1. Show the form
2. Make the text section read-only
3. Run your piece of code which generates your display text
4. Make the text section read-write
5. Add the display text to the text section
6. Make the text section read-only again

Use a [QTextEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#setReadOnly) to hold your text.

The command to make the QTextEdit read-only is:

```
QTextEdit.setReadOnly (self, bool ro)
```

So in practice this would be:

```
my_text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
```

and to change back to read-write:

```
my_text_edit.setReadOnly(False)
```